# loop and offset to determine cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have to a point in my VBA venture where i cannot avoid using loops. This time I have to do it with an offset method as well. I have looked at other postings, but the code was very long and looked complicated enough that I couldn't figure out how to simplify them for my needs. I hope someone can assist me.
I have a table in excel and all of my columns in my table have a name (makes VBA easier in my opinion). I am trying to perform a worksheet_activiate trigger that will loop through each row in column C (named "recordstatus"). And if the cell value equals "in process", then look 5 columns over at Column I (named "DeliveryDueDate"). If delivery due date is less than newdate (newdate I have already defined in my code) then record status equals "Open", else keep it as "In Process".

Below is the code I have so far. I have tested the looping and the lopping works, but will set all records to "open" even if the delivery due date is greater than what I define in the code. I have also tested to make sure the code comes back with the correct date range and it does. The code just doesn't seem to recognize my offset to look at the date and determine if the record status should change or stay the same. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am at the tail end of this project!!! :-)

```
Dim c As Range

For Each c In Range("recordstatus")
   If c.Value = "In Process" Then

      Dim today As Date
      Dim newdate As Date

      today = Now()
      newdate = today + 60
 
      If c.Offset(, 5) < newdate Then
         MsgBox ("works")
         c.Value = "Open"
      Else
         c.Value = "In Process"
      End If
  End If
Next
```

Comment: I is actually 6 columns from C?

Comment: Probably also worth checking there's actually a value in Col I before you make the comparison with `newdate`

Comment: ha ha, yes your correct SJR. I forgot I had a hidden column so it threw off my count. I adjusted it, and it seems to be working fine now. I cant believe I did that. Thanks for making me look at it again.

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks for the feedback. The delivery date is inputted from the userform but I checked my validation settings for that field afterupdate event I didnt have a validation for that. Now I do so that will take care of that! Thanks again!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Utilize Named Range

- One of the reasons of using named ranges is to avoid using the wrong ranges (columns).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub updateProgress()
    
    Dim src As Range
    Set src = Range("DeliveryDueDate")

    Dim tgt As Range
    Set tgt = Range("recordstatus")
    
    Dim today As Date
    today = Now()
    Dim newdate As Date
    newdate = today + 60

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To tgt.Cells.Count
        If tgt.Cells(i).Value = "In Process" Then
            If src.Cells(i) < newdate Then
                MsgBox "works"
                tgt.Cells(i).Value = "Open"
            Else
                tgt.Cells(i).Value = "In Process"
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: love the code. Thank you. I'm going to give this a try also and make sure I understand everything you gave me so I can better Understand looping and offsets together.